# Screen-aligned quad in clipspace is drawing atop nearer elements

Tags: scenekit, metal

I have a textured quad that needs to be drawn in screenspace, sized/aligned to the viewport, in a `SceneKit` scene at the far plane - think of it like a textured quad to act as a background fill.

I've manually created a 4 vertex quad in clip space, and written a vertex/fragment shader to draw it. The vertices are set to be at z=1, which should place them at the far plane.

However, while the quad is correctly rendered as expected in screen space (e.g., it is correctly aligned) it is drawn **atop** all scene contents - with z=1 for the clip space vertices it should be **behind** everything.

I've been able to work around this by setting a low `renderingOrder` and disabling depth writes, but that's not a fix, that's a hack.

```swift
// build the plane vertices in clip space
let vertices: [SCNVector3] = [
    SCNVector3(-1, -1, +1),
    SCNVector3(+1, -1, +1),
    SCNVector3(+1, +1, +1),
    SCNVector3(-1, +1, +1),
]

let texCoords: [CGPoint] = [
    CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1),
    CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1),
    CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0),
    CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
]

let indices: [UInt16] = [
    0,1,2,
    0,2,3,
]

let vertexSource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertices)
let texCoordSource = SCNGeometrySource(textureCoordinates: texCoords)
let elementSource = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .triangles)
let planeGeometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource, texCoordSource], elements: [elementSource])

let program = SCNProgram()
program.library = ShaderUtilities.metalLibrary
program.vertexFunctionName = "plane_vertex"
program.fragmentFunctionName = "plane_fragment"
                
if let material = planeGeometry.firstMaterial {
    material.program = program
    material.setValue(SCNMaterialProperty(contents: backdropImage as Any), forKey: "backgroundTexture")
}

let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
meshCameraNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
```

The corresponding metal shaders:

```
struct PlaneVertexIn {
    float3 position [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition)]];
    float2 uv [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticTexcoord0)]];
};

struct PlaneVertexOut {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 uv;
};

vertex PlaneVertexOut plane_vertex(PlaneVertexIn in [[ stage_in ]],
                                            constant SCNSceneBuffer& scn_frame [[buffer(0)]],
                                            constant NodeBuffer& scn_node [[buffer(1)]]) {
    PlaneVertexOut out;
    // the vertices are already in clip space to form a screen-aligned quad, so no need to apply a transform.
    out.position = float4(in.position.x, in.position.y, in.position.z, 1.0);
    out.uv = in.uv;
    return out;
}

fragment float4 plane_fragment(PlaneVertexOut out [[ stage_in ]],
                               constant SCNSceneBuffer& scn_frame [[buffer(0)]],
                               texture2d<float, access::sample> backgroundTexture [[texture(0)]]) {
    constexpr sampler textureSampler(coord::normalized, filter::linear, address::repeat);
    return backgroundTexture.sample(textureSampler, out.uv);
}
```